# Open new tab and change title with javascript

Tags: javascript

On my site, I have many links a user can click on. I have javascript (contextMenu) that allows the user to open any of the links in a new tab. When they choose to open a link in a new tab, I would like to rename the new tab based on what they clicked. However, the original tab gets renamed. Can someone show me where I am going wrong and how to rename my "New" tab instead?

```
$("#contextMenu").contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    menu: [
        { title: "Open in new tab" },
    ],
    select: function (event, ui) {

        var page = ui.target.children('a').context.nameProp;

        var parent = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');

        var parentId = ui.target.context.parentNode.parentNode.id;

        var level_three_page_name = page.substring(0, page.indexOf(".htm"));

        var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "#/search/" + parentId + "/" + level_three_page_name;

        var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');

        // The rename works correctly but the original tab gets named.
        window.document.title = level_three_page_name;

        event.preventDefault();

        window.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: `newWindow.document.title` then?

Comment: the new tab will be automagically renamed by the document you will open. Would you like to override that?

Comment: @u_mulder, I tried newWindow with no effect.

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes, I would like to override it because my users do not want multiple tabs with the same title as it gets confusing.

Comment: @MikeCollins in your example, you have "window.document.title".  Shouldn't that be "newWindow.document.title"?

Comment: @MikeCollins did you got the answer from comments?

Comment: `var level_three_page_name = page.substring(0, page.indexOf(".htm"));`
Is he mising  letter here -> .html (that means without the 'l' letter)??

Comment: @brk no I did not get an answer yet. I've tried what the comments suggest so far.

Comment: @Bigga_HD no, the "l" is not missing. The extension is supposed to be like that.